# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Server) - Rerun Installer Network Setup

Tags: networking, server

I am hoping this has an easy answer. I checked and haven't found a similar question here on Ask Ubuntu.
I ran the Ubuntu 20.04 Installer on a virtual machine and everything went fine. Because I had not configured an external adapter for the VM yet, I chose to proceed with the installation without selecting eth0 for my network connection. It went fine.

On restart, I obviously couldn't connect to the network. I shut down the machine, configured my virtual adapter for the VM and restarted the machine. On restart, despite having an external adapter, my new installation had no network connectivity. I suspected that I didn't have any configurations for the new adapter because I skipped the setup during installation.

First, I confirmed that the new adapter was detected.

`ip a` showed that eth0 was DOWN

I started the adapter using `ip link set eth0 up` and confirmed it was up by re-running ip a`.

This did not resolve connectivity. Moreover, on restart, the default setting is always **DOWN**.

I finally got connectivity when I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` to read

```
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

What bothers me about this is that even though I have connectivity now, when I compare this `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the same file I have on another working Ubuntu installation, one that had its network interface configured automatically during installation, the other Ubuntu machine does not have any data in its `/etc/network/interfaces` file. How is that other Ubuntu machine configured?

I suspect I am going to have issues with this manually edited `/etc/network/interfaces` file moving forward, and I would like to re-run the tool that sets up networking during the Ubuntu installation. What is that tool and how do I re-run the tool?

Answer (score 4):

A little more poking and help from a friend and we figured it out.

Although I had tried editing the `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file, I didn't know I had to run `sudo netplan apply` before it would take effect.

So the solution in summary is as follows:

1. Open `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
   ```
2. Edit the file to read as follows:

   ```
   #This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
        network:
          ethernets:
            eth0:
              dhcp4: true
          version: 2
   ```
3. Exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) and save (Write buffer? <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
4. Now apply the configuration:

   ```
   sudo netplan apply
   ```
5. Restart.

   ```
   shutdown -r +0
   ```

On restart, `ip a` will show a working eth0 connection and `ping 8.8.8.8` works!

Comment: Did you reference any documentation, etc., to help you figure this out? I am stuck in network hell.

Answer (score 0):

This works more or less for me too. However, I created a new file named `01-network-manager-all.yaml`, whose content is:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

I am using a Gigabyte x570i motherboard and the Ethernet chip set is Intel.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 Server (which uses `netplan` for networking) to `ubuntu-desktop` using `tasksel` for the GUI frontend for Ubuntu server (however, Desktop uses `network-manager` for networking) so after searching for some solution, this works for me.